# Unable to build SignalR.Android because of missing System.Net.Http

Tags: .net, xamarin.android, signalr, xamarin, signalr.client

I'm trying to use SignalR in my MonoDroid project. So I downloaded DEV branch from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev and when I open solution for Android, it is not possible to build it, because of missing System.Net.Http. All others dll are loaded correctly.

I have this issue for MonoDroid version 4.6.4 and also for beta version 4.7.4. Can you please help me, where can I find this dll file?

Many thanks for your help Pavol

Comment: I have the same problem, apparently they forgot to include System.Net.Http on the android beta for 4.7.4, as the iOS install has that dll. Unfortunately I don't have a mac available and I'm not able to find the file on their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Beta version but I'm not sure if that available on windows.[image]